# Boundary of open set in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

**Question**

Consider **open** set of real numbers $A$ such that $A\ne\emptyset$ and $A\ne \mathbb{R}$. Denote by $Bd(A)$ a set of boundary points of $A$. Is it true that $Bd(A)\ne\emptyset$?

It seems that according to the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629826/if-a-set-is-proper-and-non-empty-then-its-boundary-is-non-empty) the statement is true. However it uses the fact that $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are the only sets of real numbers that are open and closed simulteneously. However I whant to use abovementioned statement as a lemma to proof that $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are the only clopen sets. Therefore any alternative proof or comments on mistakes on my understanding of [this answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1629826/if-a-set-is-proper-and-non-empty-then-its-boundary-is-non-empty) are hygly appreciated.

**Cosiderations**

I think that the statement is true since **intuition** suggests that boundary point will be supremum (or infinum) of some interior neighborhood of point from $A$ and this supremum (or infinum) will be a point outside of $A$. For example for an open set $A=(-\infty,1)$ we may choose some interior neighborhood $N_{0.1}(0.9)=(0.8,1)$. Then it's supremum is $\sup(N)=1\notin A$ that is also a boundary point of $A$ so $Bd(A)\ne\emptyset$.

**Proof**

My attempt of **direct proof** in general case is as follows.

Since $A\ne\emptyset$ there is $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x\in A$.

Consider a set:
$$S = \{\varepsilon>0:N_{\varepsilon}(x)\subset A\},$$

where $N_{\varepsilon}(x)=(x - \varepsilon, x + \varepsilon)$ is an open interval.

Since $A\ne \mathbb{R}$ there is $y\in\overline{A}$ where $\overline{A}=\mathbb{R}-A=\{t\in \mathbb{R}:t\notin A\}$.

Consider $\varepsilon^{*}>|x-y|$ then:

$$[x - |x-y|, x + |x-y|]\subset(x-\varepsilon^{*},x+\varepsilon^{*})=N_{\varepsilon^{*}}(x),$$

where:

$$[x - |x-y|, x + |x-y|]=\begin{cases}
[y,2x-y]\text{, if }x>y\\
[2x-y,y]\text{, if }x<y
\end{cases}.$$

Hence $y\in N_{\varepsilon^{*}}(x)$ so $N_{\varepsilon^{*}}(x)\not\subset A$ implying that $\varepsilon^{*}$ is an upper bound of $S$. Consequently by the **completeness axiom** $S$ has supremum $\sup(S)$. The **idea** is to show that $x-\sup(S)$ or $x+\sup(S)$ is a boundary point of $A$.

There are two possible cases.

**Case 1.** Suppose $\sup(S)\in S$. Then $N_{\sup(S)}(x)=(x-\sup(S),x+\sup(S))\subset A$. Since $\sup(S)$ is supremum of $S$ **for any** $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $\sup(S)+\varepsilon\notin S$ so:

$$N_{\sup(S)+\varepsilon}(x)=(x-\sup(S)-\varepsilon,x+\sup(S)+\varepsilon)\not\subset A.$$

Combining this result with the fact that $N_{\sup(S)}(x)\subset A$ we get:
$$(x-\sup(S)-\varepsilon, x-\sup(S)]\not\subset A,$$
or
$$[x+\sup(S), x+\sup(S)+\varepsilon)\not\subset A.$$

Consider any $\varepsilon$ such that the latter holds (for the former case arguments are similar so they are omitted for brevity), then:

$$[x+\sup(S),x+\sup(S)+\varepsilon)\subset(x+\sup(S)-\varepsilon,x+\sup(S)+\varepsilon)=N_{\varepsilon}(x+\sup(S)).$$

Consequently $N_{\varepsilon}(x+\sup(S))\cap \overline{A}\ne\emptyset$. Let's denote it result **1)**.

Further observe that:

$$N_{\varepsilon}(x+\sup(S))\cap N_{\sup(S)}(x)=(x+\sup(S)-\varepsilon, x+\sup(S))\ne\emptyset\text{, if }\sup(S)\geq\varepsilon.$$

$$N_{\varepsilon}(x+\sup(S))\cap N_{\sup(S)}(x)=(x-\min(\sup(S), \varepsilon - \sup(S)), x+\sup(S))\ne\emptyset\text{, if }\sup(S)<\varepsilon.$$

Since $N_{\sup(S)}(x)\subset A$ we get that $N_{\varepsilon}(x+\sup(S))\cap N_{\sup(S)}(x)\ne\emptyset$ implies $N_{\varepsilon}(x+\sup(S))\cap A\ne\emptyset$. Let's denote it result **2)**.

By definition of boundary point results **1)** and **2)** imply that $x+\sup(S)\in Bd(A)$ so $Bd(A)\ne\emptyset$.

**Case 2.** Suppose $\sup(S)\notin S$. Then $N_{\sup(S)}(x)=(x-\sup(S),x+\sup(S))\not\subset A$. Since $x\in A$ we have $(x-\sup(S),x)\not\subset A$ or $(x,x+\sup(S))\not\subset A$. Without loss of generality suppose latter. Then since $(x,x+\sup(S))\not\subset A$ there is $z\in (x,x+\sup(S))$ such that $z\notin A$ so $(x,z]\not\subset A$. Since **$\mathbb{R}$ is dense** there is $z^{*}\in R$ such that $z<z^{*}<\sup(S)$ so $(x,z]\subset(x,z^{*})$ hence $(x,z^{*})\not\subset A$. Consider $\varepsilon = z^{*} - x$. Since $z^{*}<x+\sup(S)$ we get $\varepsilon+x<x+\sup(S)$. Hence there is $\varepsilon < \sup(S)$ such that $N_{\varepsilon}(x)\not\subset A$ so $\varepsilon$ is upper bound of $S$ that is contradiction to the fact that $\sup(S)$ is supremum of $S$. Consequently this case is impossible.

Q.E.D.

**P.S.**

Will be extremely grateful for any comments on my proof as well as for disproof or alternative proof of the statement!

**Edit**

Following comment of **Anne Bauval** (thank you very much for the response!) I have removed "without loss of generality" statement.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1629826/42969 for a shorter argument.

Comment: Although the proof in the duplicate is more general and simpler, I have been reading yours carefully. The only criticism I have is in case 1, when you write "$(x-\sup(S)-\varepsilon, x-\sup(S)]\not\subset A$ or $[x+\sup(S), x+\sup(S)+\varepsilon)\not\subset A,$ wlog suppose latter." The problem is that we may be in the former case for some $\varepsilon$'s and in the latter for other ones.